# Having trouble with summation and for loops

Tags: java, for-loop

I am supposed to code this statement as a summation:

> Subtotal = The sum (from i=1 to n) P(i)
>
> where n is the number of item bought and P(i) the price of item i.

The following is the code I have up with till now but I'm stuck cause I can't figure out the code for the above statement about calculating the subtotal:

```
 public class ItemCost {
   public static void main (String []args){
    int i=1,e=1;
    int items,  d, item ;
    double gst, qst, subt, Tot, PriceItems, ;
    Scanner x = new Scanner(System.in);
    Scanner y = new Scanner(System.in);

    System.out.println("Please input the amount of items bought");
    items = x.nextInt();

    while ( items < 1 || items > 10)    
    {
        System.out.print("Sorry the input was not correct, please try again\n");
        items = x.nextInt();
        i++;
    } 

  do 
  {
      System.out.print("Please input the price of the item  "+item + " " );
      PriceItems = y.nextDouble();
       if 
       ( PriceItems < 1 || PriceItems > 100 )
           e++;
       else
      item++;
  }while (item <= items);

   for (item = 1 ; item==items ; item++  )
}
}
```

Comment: What exact output you want?

Comment: I want to be able to add my output of PriceItems. So if someone buys 3 item and inputs a different price for all of them, I want to be able to add the price of PriceItems1 + PriceItems2 + PriceItems3

Comment: It would be great If you can possible provide exact output or requirement you want for the same

Answer (score 0):

Add `PriceItems` to `Tot`:

```
Tot += PriceItems
```

By the way, all your variables should begin with a lowercase, except constants which should be entirely in uppercase.

Comment: Entirely UPPERCASE_WITH_UNDERSCORE

Comment: ahhh alright, thank you. My teacher doesn't cover conventions in class.  Furthermore, mind explaining me how the tot += priceItems would do actually? I thought it had to be included with the for loop

Comment: You for loop does nothing useful, you can remove it. Sorry I don't understand your question.

Comment: mhm I thought loops had to be used when sigma notation was in question ( i.e: variable in the equation can change). Also, secondly, can I ask you, when writting Tot += PriceItems , the program declares Tot has not initialized.  Sorry, I am new to programming in general

Comment: Plus, taking into account the command you gave above, the program takes into account only the last input from the user ( i.e: if user inputs 10 item in the do statement, the program will only take into account the 10th input not all of them). Any tips on how to resolve that?

Comment: See the `do { ... } while(...)` block? That's a loop. You are updating `PriceItems`'s value after every user input. Add my code there.

Comment: A loop is just a block of code which is run multiple times. You *do not need* loops in order to use variables that can change. Unless declared `final`, you're allowed to change any variable. Initialize `Tot` with an assignment: `Tot = 0.0;`.

Comment: You seem to be a very beginner. I suggest you to 1) go back to some basics (variable definition, variable declaration, variable assignment, loops, etc.) 2) print your variables as often as you want using `S`, or learn how to use a debugger (Eclipse has one, it's free).

Answer (score 0):

Here I have updated some code. Please check it. Hope it helps.!!

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class ItemCost {
   public static void main (String []args){
    int e=1;
    int items,  d, item ;
    double gst, qst, subt = 0.0, tot, priceItems ;
    Scanner x = new Scanner(System.in);
    Scanner y = new Scanner(System.in);


    System.out.println("How many items do you want to bough? Enter value between 1-10");
    Scanner itenNumner = new Scanner(System.in);

    int totalItemNumber = itenNumner.nextInt();
    Scanner itemPrice = new Scanner(System.in);
    for(int itemCount = 1; itemCount<= totalItemNumber; itemCount++){

        System.out.println("Please enter price for item " + itemCount);
        double tempprice = itemPrice.nextDouble(); 
        subt=subt + + tempprice; 
    }


    System.out.println("Total price for  "+ totalItemNumber + "items is " + subt);


   }
}
```

**Following is output**

```
How many items do you want to bough? Enter value between 1-10
3
Please enter price for item 1
20
Please enter price for item 2
10
Please enter price for item 3
15
Total price for  3  items is 45.0
```

Comment: Hey, if you don't mind I'd like to ask a few questions about the change ( not that i don't agree), just so I understand. in my first while loop, I installed a counter because I have to count if ever there are errors created by the input of the user. Furthermore, in the first scanner (itenNumber), if the person  enters more ( or less) than the asked value, the program should create a loop, hence the WHILE loop. I have to add a counter to all of them, that's why I used a WHILE loop because I didn't know how to do it with the for loop. Without the counter my project is wrong.

Comment: For more or less value you can one add if condition before the for loop. It will restricted user to enter few values only. I am not getting why you have required counter like you are taking a value from user one by one for item and then you are taking a price for each one of them. Instead of that you can take total number of items and then you take input price from user for each item. !!!

Comment: because it is just required in my project to take a counter. I just have to indicate how many mistake the person made at the end of the program. I have to set restrictions on item ( from 1 --> 10). Restriction on price ( 1--->1000) and on taxes.

Comment: In your case if you are taking a item number one by one then user can enter list of items also you have not provide a limit. like user can enter items value in between 1-10 but he can enter it to unlimited times. To set restrictions on item ( from 1 --> 10). Restriction on price ( 1--->1000) and on taxes. you can just add if condition before loop and price in loop.

Comment: Where is the counter you have written in you first while loop?